# Move an entire folder to another folder that filters out using its date using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to move some folders with all of their contents that are less than the year 2015.

for example:

> SOURCE FOLDER:
>
> Folder1     2013-06-09
>
> Folder2     2014-05-10
>
> Folder3     2015-10-09
>
> DESTINATION FOLDER:
>
> Empty(no files yet)

----------RESULT:------------

> SOURCE FOLDER:
>
> Folder3     2015-10-09
>
> DESTINATION FOLDER:
>
> Folder1     2013-06-09
>
> Folder2     2014-05-10

As you can see "Folder3" was left behind the source folder because it is not less than the year 2015. Both "Folder1" and "Folder2" was moved to the Destination Folder because they are both less than the year 2015.

If any one could help me that would be great!

Comment: Is the date always at the end of the folder name? Or is the date from the folder attribute (create date or last modified date) ?

Comment: it is the create date. it is not included in the folder name.

Answer (score 2):

WMIC can be used to list the relevant folders based on creation date in a way that is independent of locale date format.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "sourceDrive=c:"
set "sourcePath=\source\"
set "destination=c:\destination"
set "year=2015"

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic fsdir where "drive='%sourceDrive%' and path='%sourcePath:\=\\%' and installDate<'%year%0101'" get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%F in ("%%A") do move "%%~fF" "%destination%"
```

Notes:

- WMIC WHERE clause ignores case
- The sourcePath must be terminated with `\`
- All `\` within sourcePath must be escaped as `\\` when used in a WMIC WHERE clause
- WMIC WHERE clause expects a date as a string in `'YYYYMMDD'` format
- The second FOR /F is used to strip the unwanted trailing carriage return character that is an artifact of improper conversion of WMIC unicode output to ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

cd "\Source Folder"
for /D %%a in (*) do for /F "tokens=3 delims=/ " %%b in ("%%~Ta") do (
   if %%b lss 2015 (
      move "%%a" "\Destination Folder"
   )
)
```

Comment: As per comment, the OP is looking for Create Date, but this uses Last Modified date.

Comment: Also, this solution is dependent on the locale date format.